# UITableViewStyleGrouped with headers for Grouped AND Plain

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I subclassed UITableViewController and set a UITableView with GroupedStyle as it's subview. When I run my project in the Simulator the section headers appear twice: In GroupedStyle and in PlainStyle. Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? I've attached the functions that I believe could be the culprits below.

[image: 2 section headers in Simulator]

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
[self setup];
self.title=@"Literature";
UITableView *tableview = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
tableview.scrollEnabled=NO;
tableview.delegate=self;
tableview.dataSource=self;
[self.view addSubview:tableview];
[tableview release];
return self;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
NSInteger inte=2;
switch (section) {
    case 0:
        inte=2;
        break;
    case 1:
        inte=4;
        break;
}
return  inte;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 2;
}
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
NSString *temp;
switch (section) {
    case 0:
        temp=@"Literature";
        break;
    case 1:
        temp=@"Online";
        break;
}
return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableViewController creates a table view for you and sets it to a property named tableView.  It also sets the delegate and the data source, to itself.  So, all the lines of code you have to do these things are redundant.

The problem comes from creating a new table view and adding it as a subview.  Thus, you now have 2 table views, the one you added as a subview and the one the UITableViewController created as the tableView property.

I suspect that the displays you're getting are the result of two overlapping table views.  One of the table views is the one that you set to GroupedStyle and the other one is in the default PlainStyle.

You can refer to the [UITableViewController class documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007523).

Comment: You are awesome! :) Thanks a lot. Now everything works fine. :)